# Qualtrics: How to loop over drill down results?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to set up a Qualtrics survey with a Drill Down question. In the first dropdown the user chooses an instructor, then the second dropdown populates with the courses offered by the chosen instructor.

What I need to do is loop through all of the courses that are populated in the second dropdown (not just selected courses, all courses) in order to present a question for each course. When answers have been given for each course the survey is complete.

I suspected it was an issue with Qualtrics being unable to loop over a Drill Down question, so I have attempted to pipe all courses for a chosen instructor to a separate question (see code below), then loop over that. This doesn't work as Qualtrics doesn't seem to be able to loop over a dynamically generated field.  Also, manually creating display logic through the interface isn't an option because there are over 200 instructors, each with multiple courses.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  var ddl1 = document.getElementById("QR~QID1~1"); //Instructor
  var ddl2 = document.getElementById("QR~QID1~2"); //Courses
  var ddl3 = document.getElementById("QR~QID2"); // Separate dropdown with results from Courses Drill Down
  //jQuery("#"+this.questionId).hide();

  // When user selects Instructor dropdown
  ddl1.onchange = function(element) {
    if (ddl1.options[ddl1.selectedIndex].text !== '') {
      // Load array with courses for selected instructor
      var ddl2Array = new Array();
      for (i = 0; i < ddl2.options.length; i++) {
        ddl2Array[i] = ddl2.options[i].text;
      }
      console.log(ddl2Array);
      //Clear all previous items from ddl3
      ddl3.options.length = 0;
      // Populate ddl3 with instructor specific courses
      for (var i = 1; i < ddl2Array.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = ddl2Array[i];
        opt.value = ddl2Array[i];
        ddl3.appendChild(opt);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div id="Questions" role="main">
    <!-- rivets: if runtime.SeparatorDisplayed -->
    <div id="QID1Separator" class="Separator"></div>
    <div class="QuestionOuter BorderColor DD  QID1" id="QID1" questionid="QID1" posttag="QID1" data-runtime-remove-class-hidden="runtime.Displayed">
        <div id="QR~QID1~VALIDATION" class="ValidationError" role="alert" data-runtime-show="runtime.ErrorMsg" data-runtime-html="runtime.ErrorMsg" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="QR~QID1~SDPVALIDATION" class="ValidationError" role="alert" data-runtime-show="runtime.PDPErrorMsg" data-runtime-html="runtime.PDPErrorMsg" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="Inner BorderColor DL">
            <div class="InnerInner BorderColor">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <div class="QuestionText BorderColor">Click to write the question text</div>
                    </legend>
                    <div class="QuestionBody">
                        <table role="presentation" class="ChoiceStructure" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="reg">
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="QR~QID1~1">Instructor</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <!-- the html binding blows aways the value binding, so do that last-->
                                        <select class="drillDownSelectDropDown QWatchTimer" name="QR~QID1~1" id="QR~QID1~1" data-runtime-select-options="runtime.Choices.1.optionHTML" data-runtime-enabled="runtime.Choices.1.enabled" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.1.Value">
                                            <option aria-label="Blank"></option>
                                            <option value="1">Smith</option>
                                            <option value="5">Johnson</option>
                                            <option value="8">Baker</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="alt">
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="QR~QID1~2">Course</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <!-- the html binding blows aways the value binding, so do that last-->
                                        <select class="drillDownSelectDropDown QWatchTimer" name="QR~QID1~2" id="QR~QID1~2" data-runtime-select-options="runtime.Choices.2.optionHTML" data-runtime-enabled="runtime.Choices.2.enabled" data-runtime-value="runtime.Choices.2.Value" disabled=""></select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- rivets: if runtime.SeparatorDisplayed -->
    <div id="QID2Separator" class="Separator"></div>
    <div class="QuestionOuter BorderColor MC  QID2" id="QID2" questionid="QID2" posttag="QID2" data-runtime-remove-class-hidden="runtime.Displayed">
        <div id="QR~QID2~VALIDATION" class="ValidationError" role="alert" data-runtime-show="runtime.ErrorMsg" data-runtime-html="runtime.ErrorMsg" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="QR~QID2~SDPVALIDATION" class="ValidationError" role="alert" data-runtime-show="runtime.PDPErrorMsg" data-runtime-html="runtime.PDPErrorMsg" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="Inner BorderColor MSB">
            <div class="InnerInner BorderColor">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        <label class="QuestionText BorderColor" for="QR~QID2">Click to write the question text</label>
                    </legend>
                    <div class="QuestionBody">
                        <div class="offScreen">To select multiple options in a row, click and drag your mouse or hold down Shift when selecting. To select non-sequential options, hold down Control (on a PC) or Command (on a Mac) when clicking. To deselect an option, hold down Control or Command and click on a selected option.</div>
                        <select role="listbox" aria-multiselectable="true" multiple="" size="10" class="ChoiceStructure QR-QID2 QWatchTimer" name="QR~QID2[]" id="QR~QID2" data-runtime-value="runtime.Selected">
                            <option role="option" class="Selection" aria-selected="false" value="QR~QID2~1" id="QR~QID2~1" data-runtime-text="runtime.Choices.1.Display">Click to write Choice 1</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="clear zero"></div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code you attempted you can post?

Comment: @TomO. Added javascript used to pipe available courses to a new question

Comment: Thanks - is there any way you can post the HTML portion too?

Comment: @TomO. Sure. HTML has been added

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the responder to choose an instructor, and then answer one question for each course offered by the instructor.

If this is the case, you do not need a drill-down question, just use two multiple-choice questions instead. I would try the following:

Q1: Choose an instructor

Q2, Q3, ..., Qn (one question for each instructor) - choose a course. Put each of these questions in a separate block. Then go to "Survey Flow" tab and add branching logic: display each block when the corresponding instructor was selected in Q1.

Then, create a loop over each instructor-specific block.